# Matrix manipulation (rotation/rolling)

Tags: java, matrix

I have this 3x3 matrix:

```
{
 [1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]
}
```

Suppose that if I send two parameters m and n, this matrix must move m and n positions (m positive / move right or negative move left) and (n positive / move down or n negative move up). For the sample if I send m = 1 , n = 0:

```
{
 [3, 1, 2],
 [6, 4, 5],
 [9, 7, 8]
}
```

Is there some kind of method to do this? Or is it just 'hard handwork'?

Comment: If you're new to Java, hard work is the way to learn...

Comment: There are no libraries for matrix manipulation in JavaSE, so you need to implement such by yourself or look for appropriate third-party library.

Comment: Shouldn't your sample should be `[[3, 1, 2], [6, 4, 5], [9, 7, 8]]`. You have correctly rotated the first row but the others look wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are prepared to use `List<List<Integer>>` instead of `int[][]` you can use [Collections.rotate(List list,int distance)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29).

```
private void rotate(List<List<Integer>> matrix, int m, int n) {
    for (List<Integer> row : matrix) {
        Collections.rotate(row, m);
    }
    Collections.rotate(matrix, n);
}

public void test() {
    int[][] m = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };
    List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int[] r : m) {
        List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int v : r) {
            row.add(v);
        }
        matrix.add(row);
    }
    System.out.println("Before: " + matrix);
    rotate(matrix, 1, 2);
    System.out.println("After: " + matrix);
}
```

Prints:

> Before: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>
> After: [[3, 1, 2], [6, 4, 5], [9, 7, 8]]

which is slightly different from what you were expecting but it looks like it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link with the documentation.